# Problem with a function similar to strcat()

Tags: c++

I tried to write a function similar to strcat() in c++.
Here is the code of this function:

```
char *mystrcat(char *str1, char *str2){
    int i = 0;
    char *buffer = str1;
    while(*str1){
        str1++; i++;
    }
    i++;
    while(*str2){
        str1[i] = *str2;
        str2++; i++;
    }
    str1[++i] = '\0';
    str1 = buffer;
    return str1;
}
```

The input values for this function are given by this code:

```
char string1[100], string2[100];
    cout << "Enter string 1 ";
    cin >> string1;
    cout << "Enter string 2 ";
    cin >> string2;
    mystrcat(string1, string2);
    cout << string1 << endl;
```

When I ran the code and tried to input two strings, it has given me this output:

```
Enter string 1 qwerty
Enter string 2 asdf
qwerty
```

Why the first string is displayed only?

Comment: `strcat()` is a C function, and this is basically C code apart from your use of `cout`.

Comment: *Why the first string is displayed only?* -- Did you check if that NULL character is in the right position?  This is where you need to debug your code.  Also, a function similar to `strcat` would have this as a prototype: `char *mystrcat(char *str1, const char *str2)`

Comment: Tip: Use pointers *or* indexes, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, since you're incrementing both `str1` *and* `i` in the first loop, you're going to move twice as fast through that array as you think. Thats because you're increasing both:

- the base of the array; and
- the offset from that base.

You're actually lucky to have chosen an even number of characters, otherwise you'd probably keep going beyond the end of `str1` (by missing the `\0`), resulting in all sorts of fun and hilarity :-)

You should increment one or the other, such as with:

```
char *mystrcat(char *str1, char *str2) {
    int i = 0;
    while(str1[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    while(*str2 != '\0')
        str1[i++] = *str2++;
    str1[i] = '\0';
    return str1;
}
```

---

The reason why you only get the first string after the concatenation, is the `i++` after the first loop (which I've removed from the above code).

When you exit that loop, `i` is the index of the `str1` terminator character so, an `i++` at that point will jump over it. That means that you'll append `str2` *after* that terminator:

```
qwerty<nul>asdf<nul>
```

Hence the string will only be `qwerty` because C strings always stop at the first terminator.

---

I often find it's useful to be able to start with a memory map and variable register (on paper), then run the code in your head, changing variables along the way. It helps to understand how your program will work. You can start with something like:

```
                 1         2
Index: 012345678901234567890
str1:  qwerty_
str2:  asdf_
i:     0
```

Then, each line of code in your head will result in `i` changing, or the string memory blocks changing (the `_` at the end indicates the string terminator).

Answer (score 1):

Don't increment the string pointers. Do just

```cpp
while (str1[i]) {
    ++i;
}
```

And start with iterating `str2` with another variable, from `0`.

What you are doing currently is basically: `str1[12] = str[6]`

When you want: `str1[6] = str2[0]`